# Agregar una clase sellada a un textImputLayout en android studio kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Estoy haciendo el proyecto de un juego, en donde mi clase personaje, tiene algunos atributos, y entre uno de esos atributos es tipo raza a la cual son 10 personajes, no se si sea mejor hacer un enum para esto o una clase sellada, teniendo en cuenta que necesito que estas 10 razas deben tener un dombre definido y su imagen, y como podria yo implementar ya sea un enum o una lista sellada en un select item layaout. No tengo codigo porque la verdad no se como hacer esto.

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Yo crearía un clase Raza, con un constructor private. Dentro de la clase Raza coloco todos las propiedades y funciones necesarias de la raza, además creo 10 variables estaticas (una por cada raza) ejemplo: public static Raza Orco =new Orco(arg1, arg2, etc). Esto provoca un comportamiento muy similar a la enumeración. Ya que tú puedes llamar a cada raza como Raza.Orco, Raza.mago.